# Can anyone show me a good source to learn web services?

Tags: php, web-services

I currently don't know any thing about web services, except that they are used to allow an application to share its functions.

- Where & how to start?
- Does any book on web services work with me if I use PHP as my programming language?
- Does anyone know any IRC channel for help?
- Does anyone know of a directory for tutorials for a beginner?
- Is it complicated?
- Does it take a long time to learn?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've used two good books in the past that focus on web services and PHP.  [Professional Web APIs with PHP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0764589547) is good if you want to quickly get started *using* 3rd party APIs (like Amazon, Google, eBay, etc.).  It has tons of example PHP code to get you started.  [Pro PHP XML and Web Services](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590596331) is what you want if you're interested in *implementing* web services of your own using PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Web services are not hard to learn. If you already have PHP experience then you know most of what you need to do a web service. This [article](http://webservices.xml.com/pub/a/ws/2004/03/24/phpws.html) might start you off creating your first web service in php.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you start with Apache Axis2. Go through [Axis2/C](http://ws.apache.org/axis2/c/docs/index.html) and [Axis2/Java](http://ws.apache.org/axis2/1_4/toc.html) docs. You can also find lot of useful tutorials/articles/etc on Web services in [WSO2 online library](http://wso2.org/library). To start with, refer to the following couple of articles on Axis2/C.

1. [Introducing Apache Axis2/C](http://wso2.org/library/252)
2. [Apache Axis2/C - Web Services Engine](http://wso2.org/library/2406)

If you are looking for a PHP Web services framework, I suggest you try out the [WSO2 WSF/PHP](http://wso2.org/downloads/wsf/php).

I also think you will find the [PHP Web Services blog](http://phpwebservices.blogspot.com/) pretty useful.